# SQL Server 2008 Sessions

Tags: sql, session

We are extremely new to ASP.net...actually working with an outside consultant which I don't currently have access to.

I am looking for:

1. Good documentation/best practices for session and session management.
    I'm finding some info now:
    http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604
2. Review of application below for comments about how to best handle this scenario.

We have the following scenario:

1. OEM machine on floor providing status UPDATES every x.x seconds to Device_Status table.
2. When ASP.net client/user wants to view status of a particular machine, I want to notify the OEM machine on the floor to increase update rate to near real-time. Potentially with "realtimeupdate" flag in Device_Status table.
3. When ASP.net client/user moves on or logs out, update rate needs to return to x.x seconds.

Since we are very new to ASP.net, we don't have any clue about sessions and session management or if it is possible.

The only problem I see so far is if the ASP.net client connection is terminated prior to setting the "realtimeupdate" flag to 0. If this happens, the OEM machine will continue to provide real-time updates when they are no longer needed.

Comment: Is it possible to capture some sort of sessionid from the client connection and trigger a stored procedure when the connection is terminated? I've searched and searched and I just need a push in the right direction.

Comment: I found this article regarding SQL Server States: http://support.microsoft.com/?id=820782 
and this one regarding ASP.NET Session States
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87069683%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't count on a browser (or the user) to say "hey I'm done".  People walk away from thr PC, surf to stackoverflow.com, hit the X to close the browser, etc.  you'll need to code your web page to request "live" frequency with every page refresh.  and have some independent server process turn off the "live" frequency if you don't get a page refresh asking for "live" frequency after some set amount of time.  In addition to your page turning it off if the user asks for that.

Comment: thank you...the question is what "some independent server process" can do this? I think with the above links I can now find what I need to do.

Comment: "some independent server process" is some program you write that runs on the server every x minutes and determines if it needs to turn off any "live" frequency requests because it doesn't find any recent request to keep the "live" frequency" going.